# The program shows error when assembling using nasm

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, x86-16, gdt

I modified an available code to enable a20 line to switch to protected mode.
But an error pops out when assembling the code.

The code is as follows :

```
    lb_a20_check:

    pushf
    push ds
    push es
    push di
    push si

    cli

    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov di, 0x0500
    mov si, 0x0510

    mov al, byte [es:di]
    push ax

    mov al, byte [ds:si]
    push ax

    mov byte [es:di], 0x00
    mov byte [ds:si], 0xff

    cmp byte [es:di], 0xff

    pop ax
    mov byte [ds:si], al

    pop ax
    mov byte [es:di], al

    pop si
    pop di
    pop es
    pop ds

    mov ax, 0                ;if memory wrapped - protected mode disabled
    je lb_en_a20

    popf
    mov ax, 1                ;if memory not wrapped
    ret

    lb_en_a20:

        popf

        mov dl, var_temp_a20
        cmp dl, 0x01
        je lb_en_KEYBOARD_a20

        cmp dl, 02
        je lb_en_FAST_a20 

        lb_en_BIOS_a20:

            mov ax, 0x2401
            int 0x15

            inc dl
            mov var_temp_a20, dl

            jmp lb_a20_check

        lb_en_KEYBOARD_a20:

            cli
            call fn_wait_kb_cmd

            mov al, 0xAD             ;disable keyboard
            out 0x64, al

            call fn_wait_kb_cmd

            mov al, 0xD0
            out 0x64, al

            call fn_wait_kb_data

            in al, 0x60
            push eax

            call fn_wait_kb_cmd

            mov al, 0xD1
            out 0x64, al

            call fn_wait_kb_cmd

            pop eax
            or al, 2
            out 0x60, al

            call fn_wait_kb_cmd

            mov al, 0xAE
            out 0x64, al

            call fn_wait_kb_cmd

            sti
            inc dl
            mov var_temp_a20, dl

            jmp lb_a20_check

        lb_en_FAST_a20:

            in al, 0x92
            or al, 02
            out 0x92, al

            inc dl
            mov var_temp_a20, dl

            jmp lb_a20_check

lb_a20_data:

    var_temp_a20 db 0

lb_a20_include_data:

    %include 'include\kb.asm'
```

The code is simple but the error pops out whenever i uses the memory var_temp_a20 in any statement.

The error says incorrect opcode or operand at the statements :

```
mov var_temp_a20, dl
```

everywhere throughout the program.

Can anybody interpret the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `var_temp_a20` declared?

Comment: What about `mov BYTE [var_temp_a20], dl`?

Comment: @FUZxxl It is declared in the same file to the end as "var_temp_a20 db 0"

Comment: @Marget Bloom yes!! Its working. But how is it possible? var_temp_a20 is already a single byte memory variable then why specify BYTE separately? Can you please explain so as this problem doesn't occur again...

Comment: @PantherCoder The brackets did the trick. `BYTE` was for elegance only.

Comment: [NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2)